# Opening my XML that references a XSL opens everything in a line

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file that references a XSL so that when I open the XML file in a browser it automatically applies the transformation.

However, when I open the file it all appears in the same line with no format at all. However, if I form an output file with Netbeans it opens everything nice and sectioned where it should be. Is there anyway to make it open in the browser automatically like that?

Thank you.

EDIT: Pic of the result: [image: image of the result]

Pic of what I would like:

[image: image of what I want]

Comment: An example (preferably minimized) would be useful, IMHO.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, edited in two pics!

Comment: I meant show us the **code** (XML + XSLT).

Comment: The website keeps complaining when I try to post it but the problem isn't in the code since it produces a normal output from Netbeans, but when I open the original XML it applies the transformation well, it just doesn't show the info well. Sorry for the lack of info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collapsible tree format is simply the way a browser displays XML files that *don't* have any stylesheet associated with them.  When you ask a browser to apply a stylesheet the browser (quite rightly) assumes that the purpose of the stylesheet is to transform the input XML into something that the browser knows how to render (HTML, SVG, MathML, etc.) and it will attempt to render the result rather than showing the XML tree structure.  The "single line" appearance is simply what browsers do when asked to render XML elements they don't understand - they treat them the same as inline HTML elements like `span`.

Comment: oh so there's nothing to do then? Thank you for the explanation aswell!